# How to add total line count of file to vim status bar

Tags: vim

How can I edit my status bar to always display the total number of lines in the open file?

Looked at [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline), but didn't see an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
set statusline =%1*\ %n\ %*            "buffer number
set statusline +=%5*%{&ff}%*            "file format
set statusline +=%3*%y%*                "file type
set statusline +=%4*\ %<%F%*            "full path
set statusline +=%2*%m%*                "modified flag
set statusline +=%1*%=%5l%*             "current line
set statusline +=%2*/%L%*               "total lines
set statusline +=%1*%4v\ %*             "virtual column number
set statusline +=%2*0x%04B\ %*          "character under cursor
```

[image: vim statusline]

And here's the colors I used:

```
hi User1 guifg=#eea040 guibg=#222222
hi User2 guifg=#dd3333 guibg=#222222
hi User3 guifg=#ff66ff guibg=#222222
hi User4 guifg=#a0ee40 guibg=#222222
hi User5 guifg=#eeee40 guibg=#222222
```

Answer (score 2):

[Example of statusline results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KffW3.png)

If you wanted to make this small addition to the default airline statusline
instead of writing a new statusline, you can update the appropriate airline
section.

In my case I added the total line count after the current line number like `3/45`.

Airline's section with the current line number is z, which you can check by
running `echom g:airline_section_z` which should returns something like:

`%3p%% %{g:airline_symbols.linenr}%#__accent_bold#%4l:%#__restore__#%3v`

You can update it to include the vim statusline code for total line number `%L`

`%3p%% %{g:airline_symbols.linenr}%#__accent_bold#%4l`**/%L**`:%#__restore__#%3v`

I also moved the `%#__restore__#` back a little to make the current line number
the only thing bolded.

`%3p%% %{g:airline_symbols.linenr}%#__accent_bold#%4l%#__restore__#/%L:%3v`

Test with `let g:airline_section_z = 'test string here'` followed by `:AirlineRefresh` until you get it right, then make it stick in the vimrc with:

`function! AirlineInit()
    let g:airline_section_z = 'your string'
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call AirlineInit()`

Which is apparently the [canonical](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues/482) way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Using the [airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin, I solved this problem by adding the following lines of code to my init.vim file. If you are using [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) instead of [Neovim](https://neovim.io/), put them in your vimrc file instead.

```
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_section_z = airline#section#create(['%3p%%: ', 'linenr', '/%3L', ':%3v'])
```

[The result of using the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SAnC.jpg)